# Select object and add to list linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

probably a simple Q but still a beginner at this and not sure on how to....
Each WorkStation can have a number of Invoices So my below code will....

store all the workStations, go Through each workStation,
get the last (most recent) invoice for that workStation,
If the invoices date (for the most recent Invoice) is < 12 Months

### Add it to the list of sites...

EDIT:
   Thanks for all the help guys but I am trying to do it through c# and avoid the LINQ searche you guys have mentioned...thanks for everyone who replied...

My new problem being i need to sort the ChosenInvoices list into asceding order and return the first...as i think it is selecting anyone in the list:

```
 var allWorkSites =
            (from worksites in db.Work_Sites
             select worksites).Distinct().ToList();
    List<Object> chosenInvoices = new List<Object>();

    foreach (Work_Site worksite in allWorksites)
    {
        Invoice lastInvoice = worksite.Invoices.LastOrDefault();

        if (lastInvoice != null)
        {
            if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
            {
                chosenInvoices.Add(workstation);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add what to the list of sites? the invoice object or the workstation object?

Comment: what is list of sites? There nothing about it in your example

Comment: @ryadavilli add the invoice object thanks

Comment: @Ph0en1x sorry about that meant to be workstation

Comment: There is something off about your class/list design, you want go through all workstations and then get last invoice for each and then add an invoice to your list of workstations ? You need better naming of your classes, or need to relook at your logic.

Comment: Ok, if the invoice has an actual date you need to add your workstation to some list, right?

Comment: @ryadavilli, yes I suppose you are correct...how about then...go through all workstations, get the last invoice of each workstation and add it to a new list? ChosenWorkStations?? any help?

Comment: @Ph0en1x yeah if the previous invoice for each workstation has a date of before today -12 months then add it to a new list

Comment: List<Object> chosenIvoicesForRetention = new List<Object>(); if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
            {
                chosenIvoicesForRetention.Add(lastInvoice);
            }

Comment: Pleas see my edit of original post..does it look ok

Comment: Do you have a WorkStation navigation property in Invoice class, or not ?

Comment: check the answer by @dutzu below. fits your requirements.

Comment: @ryadavilli no. All answers return workStations, not invoices.

Comment: @ryadavilli thanks for the help...think i got it...although it is still returning null...I thik i need to sort the list into ascending order and select the first....Please see my edit

Comment: @Ph0en1x please see above

Comment: I read your code carefully. But what is your question now? Looks like the code you write do the things you ask. I think that you asking how to write it with linq only and I provide you with the code sample.

Comment: @Ph0en1x sorry edit was a bit slow. i need a hand sorting the list if you can see my original post has just been edited. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<invoice> actualInvoices = db.Work_Stations.Distinct()
        .Where(w => w.Invoices.Last().Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)).Select(w => w.Invoices.Last()).ToList();
```

This code will return you the list of most recent invoices from each workstation.

To sort your invoice in asscending order list have a method **OrderBy()**, so order it with this method and then take the first one.

Also list have **Sort()** method.

Comment: I don't think you can be absolutely sure  that `Last()` will return the element with the most recent date.

Comment: Think it's hard to say for sure because we know just a little about it. I still do not 100% sure that get the question right.

Answer (score 2):

```
allWorkStations
    .Where(w => w.Invoices.Last().Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
    .Select(w => list.add(w));
```

Or better yet:

```
List<Work_Station> list = db.Work_Stations
    .Distinct()
    .Where(w => w.Invoices.Last().Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allWorkStations =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Stations
             where workstation.Invoices.Last().Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)
             select workstation).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create list of workstations which had invoice in last year

```
var checkDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);

var resultList = db.Work_Stations
  .Distinct()
  .Select(ws => new {Ws = ws, Li = ws.Invoices.OrderBy(i => i.Invoice_Date).LastOrDefault()})
  .Where(item => item.Li != null && Li.Invoice_Date < checkDate)
  .Select(item => item.Ws)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if the invoices are not in date order:

```
invoiceLst.AddRange(allWorkStations
    .Where(w => w.Invoices.Max(i => i.Invoice_Date) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)));
```