# Put multiple row values in object in VB.NET

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I have a stored procedure and often that procedure will return multiple rows, for example:

```
ID     Type    Price
1234    A      2.260
1234    B      2.690
1234    C      2.990
1234    D      2.690
1234    D      2.790
1234    D      2.650
1234    D      2.680
```

And I want to output the latest value for each type.  In my data reader I have:

```
While dr.Read
    result.price.TypeA= dr("price")
    result.price.TypeB= dr("price")
    result.price.TypeC= dr("price")
    result.price.TypeD= dr("price")
End While
```

and my query looks like:

```
select  sm_id,
        type,
        price
from    ** WITH (NOLOCK)
where   id = @id
order by id desc
```

I'm not sure how to store all of my results into my object so I can access them in my front end.

Comment: LINQ. LINQ is your answer. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502428/select-object-and-add-to-list-linq-c-sharp . I tried to type out an answer but there were just too many assumptions and unknowns to be coherent. One of the problems with your query is that all of the IDs appear to be the same. If that is not a typo, you will need to have a unique identifier; I suggest `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Also, your query will be to select the max ID grouped by type

Comment: "output the latest value" - how you determine latest value?

Comment: @T.S. After posting this I realized I needed to query for another column.  I now have update date as a part of the query.

Comment: @rlb.usa thanks so much!  I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is may be not most performant query but it will do the job as what you described it

```sql
select t1.id, t1.t, t1.maxDt, t2.price
from 
    (select id, [TYPE] t, MAX(ud) maxDt 
     from dbo.a it
     where id =1 
     group by id, [type]) t1 
         left join
     dbo.a t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.t = t2.[type] and t1.maxDt = t2.ud
```

Now, storing results in object and displaying it

```vb
Public Class MyClass
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property [Type] As String
    Public Property [Date] As DateTime
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class

. . . . . 

Dim myList As New List(Of MyClass)()
While dr.Read()
    Dim item As New MyClass()
    item.Id = dr("id")
    item.[Type] = dr("t")
    item.[Date] = dr("maxDt")
    item.Price = dr("price")
    myList.Add(item)
End While

myDataGrid.DataSource = myList
```

This is what you, approximately, need

Comment: It's the obvious answer, yes, but it sounds like changing his query isn't what he wants to do. It sounds like he wants his cake and eat it too, which can be accomplished, but is more difficult.

Comment: @rlb.usa Lest see what he says

Comment: @T.S.  I'm totally fine with changing the query.  Is there anyway I can just pass back an entire object?  Is that what grouping accomplishes?

Comment: @ryandonohue Please see my updated answer. This should be good start for you. Grouping accomplishes selecting max date / per type